# Angular Paginator pagination page size option select is under page

Tags: angular, typescript, select, mat-table, paginator

I'm using copied paginator in Mat

```html
<mat-paginator #paginator
             [length]="dataSource?.data?.length"
             [pageIndex]="0"
             [pageSize]="3"
             [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Table works correctly and paginator works correctly, but the page size option is under page. Where can be a problem?

[image: screenshot]

datasource ts:

[image: datasource]

[image: datasource]

Comment: What type of `dataSource` you are using?

Comment: It's my own class which extends DataSource<T> from @angular/cdk/collections

Comment: Could you please share the code of the data source? Also, temporarily remove the `length` binding (`[length]="dataSource?.data?.length"`) from the paginator to see if it works.

Comment: updated post. couldn't able to add code, only pics. removing length didn't gave a result

Comment: The reason I asked about the data source - `DataSource<T>` is most usually used for server-side pagination scenario. In which case the the length of data is an observable type whose value varies based on filtering. But you are doing the pagination on client side. Though may be not directly related to your current issue, you should consider using `MatTableDataSource<T>`.

Comment: No, using MatTableDataSource<T> did't fixed that

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be late, but for the others - it looks like you didn't add angular material styling: `ng add @angular/material.` You can also add your own styling.